# Looping through frames in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to loop through all frames on page and see if element is present in any of those frames. Why am I getting below exception when it cant find the element in frame. I am dealing with False `.is_displayed` output in except block.

```
    frames = [0,1,2]
    element = "//div[@class='CardNumberField-input-wrapper']//input[@name='cardnumber']"
    for frame in frames:
        driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
        if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, element).is_displayed() == True:
            print("found element " + element + " in frame " + str(frame))
            driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
        else:
            driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
            pass
```

its finding element in `frame[0]` and throwing below exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"
//div[@class='CardNumberField-input-wrapper']
//input[@name='cardnumber']"}
```

Answer (score 1):

had to wrap it in try and except block now it works fine. :)

```
    frames = [0,1,2]
    element = "//input[@name='cvc']"
    for frame in frames:
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
            if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, element).is_displayed() == True:
                print("found element " + element + " in frame " + str(frame))
                driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
        except:
            driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
            print(" element: " + element + " was not found in frame: " + str(frame))
```